# Response Header with a JsonRestStore (with Dgrid/Dojo)

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

Trying to build a dynamic grid with my json store, but for some reason there's a range constraint and I guess it's part of the dgrid/store implementation, but I should scroll down my grid and get more result from the example at dgrid site.

[image: range image]

I'll put some code in here. First, I tried to be very modular in my code, so I have a file that gets my store (content.js), a file that build my grid (gridlayout.js) and main.js (create my instance and pass my store).

**content.js**

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/xhr",
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dojo/store/JsonRest",
    "dojo/store/Cache"
    ],
function(
    xhr,
    Memory,
    JsonRest,
    Cache
){

    var contentMemoryStore = new Memory();
    var contentJsonRestStore = new JsonRest({target: "http://dev.mpact.tv:30087/rest/contenus/"});

    contentStore = new Cache(contentJsonRestStore, contentMemoryStore);

    return contentStore;
});
```

**GridLayout.js**

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
    "dgrid/Keyboard", 
    "dgrid/Selection",
    "dgrid/extensions/ColumnHider",
    "dgrid/editor",
], function(
    declare,
    _WidgetBase,
    Grid,
    Keyboard, 
    Selection,
    Hider,
    editor
){

    return declare([Grid, Keyboard, Selection, Hider], {

    columns: {
        selected: editor({
                    label: " ",
                    autoSave: true,
                    sortable: false
                }, "checkbox"),
        nom: "Name",
        autodelete: "Auto-delete",
        groupe_id: "Groupe ID",
        global: "Global",
        date: "Date",
        duree: "Lenght",
        description: "Description",
        fichier: "Filename",
        pleinecran: "Fullscreen",
        repertoire: "Folder",
        taille: "Size",
        expiration: "Expired",
        id: "id",
        catergorie: "Category",
        brouillon: "Example"
    },

    });
});
```

and my **main.js**:

```
var gridLayout = new GridLayout({}, "placeholder");
gridLayout.set("store", contentStore);
```

So far, I just 25 result and if I scroll down, I don't get the rest of my items.

Comment: How many items are there at the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in your browser shows items 0-24/25. That means the total number of items server side is 25. Hence the grid won't try to fetch more than that.

If it were returning 0-24/1000, then there would be multiple calls when you would scroll.

So I think you should check server side why it only returns 25 as **total** number of items.

Check this: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#id7

Comment: hmmm.. Not really server side it's more about the request. Check the request header.

Comment: @fneron the server should return the max number of items - check this: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#id7

Comment: ohhhh... So, I do need to set it the max/total. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#paging

Comment: Ok so fixed the response header and I get my total number of items. But when I scroll down with dgrid doesn't make any calls to render new items?

Comment: I get this error by the console in chrome : Refused to get unsafe header "Content-Range"

Comment: @fneron here is sample code working for me in java:
 String s = "" + from + "-" + (from + docs.size()) + "/" + nbItems;
 return Response.status(HttpStatus.OK.value()).
              header("Content-Range: items", s).              entity(writer.toString()).type("application/json").build();